# IOS API to adjust volume of right left stereo channel

Tags: ios

My iOS app needs to play a video file and adjust the volume of the left and right stereo channels.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

If you could separate the audio from the video you could play the audio using AudioUnit or AudioQueues and modify the amplitude of samples for left/right channel.

There are a few pitfalls with this though, syncing audio with the video, and handling (re)syncing audio if you allow the user to jump back and forth in the video using controls etc.